# How can I insert a color tag in a string? (Java)

Tags: java

If string is `Java is Great!` then how can I make it like this:

```
<font color="red">Java</font> <font color="blue">is</font> <font color="yellow">Great!</font>
```

The value of color should different for each one.

Similarly, how can I do it for all the words, e.g.

```
<font color="color1">J</font>
<font color="color2">a</font>
<font color="color3">v</font>
<font color="color4">a</font>
<font color="color5"> </font>
<font color="color6">i</font>
<font color="color6">s</font>
<font color="color7"> </font>
<font color="color8">G</font>
<font color="color9">r</font>
<font color="color10">e</font>
<font color="color11">a</font>
<font color="color12">t</font>
<font color="color13">!</font>
```

Using different String methods?

Comment: Do you mean the output on the console?

Comment: Is this for HTML output? Or console? Or Swing? Or something else? String itself is pure text, no formatting.

Comment: `<font>` tags?  Brrr.  Do yourself and your users a favor and switch to CSS, `<font>` has been deprecated for AGES.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie Even if it would be, the homework tag should not be used anymore: [Trogdor ate my homework (tag)!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag)

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie, still some confusion in codes given by ManojGumber, waiting for his reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to access each character in the string one at a time. You can do that by creating a simple loop such as this:

```
    for(Character c: myString.toCharArray()){

    }
```

It may be advisable to use a StringBuilder here since you are manipulating a string. Before the loop you can create one lik ethis:

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

To add the tag around the character in the loop you can do this:

```
  sb.append("<font color=\"color1\">");
  sb.append(c);
  sb.append("</font>");
```

After the loop you will get the new string like this:

```
 String result = sb.toString();
```

And you can do as you please with it. To get the different colors you have to decide how you are keeping those colors, say in an array, and accessing them to build the string appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @Eric.  Copy and paste dangers again.

Answer (score 2):

Its easy, try this code:

```
private final static String RED_COLOR_OPEN = "<font color=\"red\">";
private final static String RED_COLOR_CLOSE = "</font>";
```

and in your method :

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(RED_COLOR_OPEN).append(BOLD_OPEN).append(title).append(BOLD_CLOSE).append(".").append(RED_COLOR_CLOSE).trimToSize();
    sb.append(BREAK);
```

This will adjust the color to do the rest of your message

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes. Essentially it is using  three String functions -  [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) , [charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)
and [format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to manipulate the String.

```
String[] colors = {"red","blue","yellow"};
//Store the message in string
String msg = "java is great";
//Split the msg into words using String#split() method. 
//Use a regex \s+ to split the Message using space as delimiter
String[] message = msg.split("\\s+");
//Now each word in msg is available in message array.
//Iterate over each word to generate the required output format
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<message.length;i++)
{
//use the String#format() method to get the required format for String 
      s.append(String.format("<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>",
                              colors[i],message[i]);
}
String output = s.toString();
```

Also for the second solution. Have not included the colors array length check. Ensure that you have sufficient colors.

```
String[] colors = {"red","blue","yellow"};
String msg = "java is great";
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<msg.length();i++)
{
      s.append(String.format("<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>",colors[i],msg.charAt[i]);
}
String output = s.toString();
```

Update:
Added explanation

Comment: Thank you ManojGumber, you really posted something that I was looking for. Can you please explain me the meaning of these codes:`String[] message = msg.split("\\s+");` and `s.append(String.format("<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>",colors[i],msg.charAt[i]);`

Comment: @user1439416 I have added details...let me know if you need further help

Comment: Thank you very much! one more question, if my string is `Man"oj"Gumber` then how to make it `ManojGumber`? I used .replaceAll, but it is not valid for `"` char. Any practical solution for this.

Comment: @user1439416 `String[] out = input.split("\"");` Now iterate over out and concatenate each to get the result (same technique as answer)